# ListView selectedindexchanged

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, select

I need help to get a response when I click on an "Item" from a list view. Know that there is selectedindexchanged, but when I try to display a MessageBox so nothing happens, have tried lots of other things but have not managed to come up with something.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ...
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            string alio = reader["fornamn"].ToString();
            string efternamn = reader["efternamn"].ToString();
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(alio);
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(efternamn);
        }
    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms? Either way, please post your code.

Comment: Can we see what you have tried and what problems/errors you are encountering?

Comment: i use WinForms http://pastebin.com/zWanhwA4

Comment: @AliRiyadh Can you post the code that you have tried and tell us what type of .NET project you are working on? WebForms, MVC, Winforms, WPF... ? We need some more information from you.

Comment: Here is my code, i use the Framework 4.0.30 
http://pastebin.com/zWanhwA4
And i want to get data from database in to textboxes i have

Comment: @AliRiyadh: It's best to actually post the relevant code on here because links tend to die out, which would break this question in the future for anyone else having a similar issue. Please post your code here instead of linking to it.

Comment: @m-y I cant do it cuse im a new member

Comment: @AliRiyadh take a look at this answer i just posted for someone else. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9857297/459517 It demonstrates using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `ListBox`, but the principles are the same for the `ListView`. Is should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I would update your pastebin code and remove the sensitive information (user/pass/server address) from it. It's in plain site for anyone to do something malicious to your SQL database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that 81.private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged is properly linked to the listview, you will need to query the listview to find out what's selected:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(this.listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
    return;

  string namn = this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;

  // Create the sql statement to retrieve details for the user
  string sql = string.Format("select * from kunder where fornamn = '{0}', namn);

  // do the same as you do to create a reader and update the controls.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by the term "when I try to display a MessageBox so nothing happens"\, I assume that you simply put `MessageBox.Show("blah");` inside the event handler and never got it shown.

If that's the case, your event handler is not hooked properly to your form's list view. go back and see the text `listView1_SelectedIndexChanged` is anywhere to be found inside your `Form1.Designer.cs` file.

If not (or anyway), start over on a new form. That's the easiest way out. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void lstView_KQ_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (lstView_KQ.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            ListViewItem itiem = stView_KQ.SelectedItems[lstView_KQ.SelectedItems.Count - 1];
            if (itiem != null)
                foreach (ListViewItem lv in lstView_KQ.SelectedItems)
                {
                    txtMaNV.Text = lv.SubItems[0].Text;
                    cmbCV.Text = lv.SubItems[1].Text;
                    txtHoNV.Text = lv.SubItems[2].Text;
                    txtTenNV.Text = lv.SubItems[3].Text;
                    txtNgaysinh.Text = lv.SubItems[4].Text;
                    txtGioiTinh.Text = lv.SubItems[5].Text;
                    txtDiaChi.Text = lv.SubItems[6].Text;
                    txtSDT.Text = lv.SubItems[7].Text;
                    txtCMND.Text = lv.SubItems[8].Text;
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for your answer, however, what would make it an *even better* answer would be if you added explanations to what your code does, and why it works.