# Constant Check if ListView is Selected

Tags: c#, listview

I have done this before and I have a way of doing it, but I want to make sure it is the best way. I have a ListView in Details view. I also have a button. I only want that button to be enabled if there is an item selected (multiselect is disabled). Items will be added and removed to this listview but the button should be enabled anytime there is a selected item and disabled otherwise.

My event handler:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        button1.Enabled = true;
    else
        button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

That is what I have, just wondering if that will always work or are there freak incidents where it fails? Like if I delete or add things or anything else?

Comment: You say "constant check", but you really only need to check whenever an item is selected. What does your event handler for selections look like?

Comment: @Austin `        private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) button1.Enabled = true;
            else button1.Enabled = false;
        }`

Comment: @vkapadia see my answer. I tried to do it in the shortest way I could. Hope you will like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be better if you show what you have - but in short, you start with the button disabled, and in the list view selectedindexChanged event enable the button if the list view has a selectedItems.Count of 1.  Disable it if no item is selected.  Here's a link which may help:
[ListView selectedindexchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857141/listview-selectedindexchanged)

Comment: In that case what you're already doing is as good a way as I know :)

Comment: @kashif - much as I love resharper, just because it makes a suggestion doesnt make it always better - one could argue that the Op's way of having the if is better - e.g if you then decide to something else in addition to enabling the button. (Though I agree in this case it probably is neater on one line)

Comment: @NDJ i will need to do more than enable one button if an item is selected, so the if statement is necessary. thanks for both your help!

Comment: I'm having a problem now. I have code that removes an item, but then the button stays enabled even though nothing is selected.

Comment: Pvkapadia - probably because the selected index isn't changing on a removal - you could extract the check 'if item not selected then disable button' and call it from your remove method.  Doesn't invalidate the original answer though i'd have thought?

Comment: When I check listview1.SelectedItems.Count, it does change, but the event does not fire.

Comment: It does invalidate it. I dont want code that checks if the selected index has changed or not. I want code that checks if something is selected or not. I dont care if the index is the same or whatever. Basically, if item selected, button enabled, if item not selected, button disabled.

Comment: And yeah I could put the whole if statement in the remove method, but the point is, I want to know if that is the best way. Is there no simple way to do this? Do I have to put the whole if statement all over in any method that touches the listview?

Comment: I didn't say put the whole if in the remove, i said extract the if to a seperate method which checks the selected items and call that anywhere you touch the listview.  Not the prettiest, but I can't think what else there is.  Maybe somebody else will come with a better proposal

Comment: @vkapadia see my edit. when I click button two it removes the selecteditems and disables button1.

Comment: @NDJ i couldnt find a better way to do it. i'm just going to extract the code and put it in a method and call that method everywhere for now. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add("kashif");
        }
        button1.Enabled = false;            
    }
    private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0;
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem v in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {
            v.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

**Before Button2 Click**

[image]

**After Button2 click**

[image]

Comment: button1.Enabled is asking for boolean then why to put it on if condition when listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 returns bool. that is how he could make this code better

Comment: @kashif i have more complicated removal code and thats whats breaking it.